# Probem with webscraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new in using beautifulSoup and having a question; appreciate your help:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

URL = 'https://www.kbb.com/car-values/'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup1 =  soup(page.content, 'html-parser')

print(soup1.prettify())
```

In parallel, I went to the URL in a separate browser and inspect the page to get the HTML version of the page to establish patterns.
I found two independent patterns  that meet my need

yyyy1

and

yyyy2

P.S. xxxx1, xxxx2, yyyy1 and yyyy2 are just strings

I went back to the prettify() output and searched for the pattern xxxx1 and I found it but when I searched for pattern xxxx2 I could not find it?
It seems like the soup object does not contain all info in the HTML page? or I am not looking at the right HTML page?
I can not guess what I did wrong and how to do it right?

Thanks

Comment: I believe that it is possible that some of the information on the website might be loaded from other sources using javascript and therefore (as the requests library doesn't load javascript), the data is missing from the URL request. Perhaps using a heavier weight library like selenium would be useful here as it will actually load the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Initially a modification was needed to run your code, changed the 'html-parser' to 'html.parser'. This fixed the **bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html-parser. Do you need to install a parser library?**

Locally when I try your code I get:

```
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.kbb.com/" on this server.

Reference #18.afe17b5c.1587328194.c07350f
```

Are there restrictions on some countries?